# References (to where the cite was made) are added in the bibliography entries

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, back-referencing

I'm making my thesis and I see references added in the bibliography entries which are pointing to the chapter/section where I used the `citep`/`citet` command.

[image]

I want to delete them since my professor doesn't want them, but I don't know how...

This is how I'm adding the bibliography...

```
\begin{spacing}{1}
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \bibliography{bibliography}
\end{spacing}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why not use a different bibliography style if the one you're using doesn't match what you need to use? Just because somebody else at your institution wrote a style for her/his needs, there's no reason you should use the same one if it doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: @cfr It turned out that even using other style the references didn't disappear... I edited my question...

Comment: how you load`hyperref`package? if it is loaded with option `backref=...` remove this option.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks, that was the problem, there was a backref=section

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question could be solved in comments